# Windows 10 File Explorer has a duplicate name

Tags: windows, windows-10, start-menu

The problem is that the File Explorer app seems to have the wrong name "File Explorer (1)" instead of just "File Explorer" in the startmenu. Its like that for a time now, but it first appeared after a windows update. It seems to be that during the update the location where the new File Explorer was created already contained a File Explorer.

How do i change this back to the normal name?

I tried searching but there is just way to much unrelated stuff in the search results.

I tried to reach the location of the start menu entry by right clicking. Clicking "Properties" just brings up the system dialog. Any idea where this lnk or exe could be located that is showing up in the
startmenu?

[Screenshot of the start memu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf9uf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to: `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools` and check if the shortcut is named differently in this location, if it is, rename it. Your shortcut should now be correct. If this fails, please take a look in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. These are the only two locations which contain start menu entries.

Comment: Ok, it was located under the first one you mentioned and almost all entries in that folder were duplicated, thanks!